# Reading CSVs from a folder on R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

```
 d <- NULL   
 datafiles <- list.files(path = "C:___")
        for (i in datafiles){
        print(i)
        j <- read.csv(i, header = T)
        j$file <- i
             d <- rbind(d, j)
        }
```

When I ran just the print line, all of the csv names in the folder were displayed, but everything beyond the j <- line, an error pops up. When I ran the entire code, the error I got says:

```
     Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:              
 Warning message:
     In file(file, "rt") :
    cannot open file 'xxx.csv': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `list.files` is specifying a `path=`, which probably isn't the same as your working directory - compare it to `getwd()`. So when you do `read.csv`, it doesn't find the file because it's looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

file_list <- list.files()
df <- map_dfr(file_list, read_csv)
```

Or:

```
file_list <- list.files()
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file_list, read_csv))
```

Make sure to set your working directory correctly with `setwd()`.

Comment: Dplyr has a faster version of `rbind` called `bind_rows` that would work well with this pattern!

Comment: Just curious, is `bind_rows` faster than the first approach which uses purrr?

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure! I've used the purrr approach recently and was happy with it, but I haven't done any benchmarking.

Comment: One thing I do like about `bind_rows` is that it can turn named list elements or arguments into values in a new column

Comment: This question has been marked duplicate

Comment: Interesting. I may test it out with the microbench package. Thanks for sharing!